# How to disable select option from one Select based on other select in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have found here same questions but they are not in vue.js and I can't find out how to do that in vue.js.

I have 8 `select` items. They all get same `option` values from database.

```html
 <div class="card-body">
    <div>
        <label>Polje 1:</label
        ><select
            ><option
                v-for="podatak in podaci"
                :key="podatak.id"
                >{{ podatak.name }}</option
            ></select
        >
    </div>
        <div>
        <label>Polje 2:</label
        ><select
            ><option
                v-for="podatak in podaci"
                :key="podatak.id"
                >{{ podatak.name }}</option
            ></select
        >
    </div>
        <div>
        <label>Polje 3:</label
        ><select
            ><option
                v-for="podatak in podaci"
                :key="podatak.id"
                >{{ podatak.name }}</option
            ></select
        >
    </div>
        <div>
        <label>Polje 4:</label
        ><select
            ><option
                v-for="podatak in podaci"
                :key="podatak.id"
                >{{ podatak.name }}</option
            ></select
        >
    </div>
        <div>
        <label>Polje 5:</label
        ><select
            ><option
                v-for="podatak in podaci"
                :key="podatak.id"
                >{{ podatak.name }}</option
            ></select
        >
    </div>
        <div>
        <label>Polje 6:</label
        ><select
            ><option
                v-for="podatak in podaci"
                :key="podatak.id"
                >{{ podatak.name }}</option
            ></select
        >
    </div>
        <div>
        <label>Polje 7:</label
        ><select
            ><option
                v-for="podatak in podaci"
                :key="podatak.id"
                >{{ podatak.name }}<img :src="podatak.url"></option
            ></select
        >
    </div>
        <div>
        <label>Polje 8:</label
        ><select
            ><option
                v-for="podatak in podaci"
                :key="podatak.id"
                >{{ podatak.name }}</option
            ></select
        >
    </div>
</div>
```

Question:

Let's imagine they all have `options`: "A", "B", "C" and "D". For example, If I select "A" in my 2nd `select` how to disable "A" from all other `selects`?

Comment: binds `disable=true` of `<option>` if `value in selectedOptions`.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to vue.js, can  you write full code for one select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the current selected value in a data() value. Set :disabled to each option attribute if the value is matching the stored value :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
  <select @change="setSelectedValue">
    <option v-for="podatak in podaci"
            :disabled="podatak.name === selectedValue"
            :key="podatak.id">{{ podatak.name }}</option>
  </select>
  <select @change="setSelectedValue">
    <option v-for="podatak in podaci"
            :disabled="podatak.name === selectedValue"
            :key="podatak.id">{{ podatak.name }}</option>
  </select>
  <select @change="setSelectedValue">
    <option v-for="podatak in podaci"
            :disabled="podatak.name === selectedValue"
            :key="podatak.id">{{ podatak.name }}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      podaci: [
        {
          id: 0,
          name: 'aaa'
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'bbb'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'ccc'
        },
      ],
      selectedValue: null
    },
    methods: {
      setSelectedValue(event) {
        this.selectedValue = event.target.selectedOptions[0].value;
      }
    }
  })
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need. One more question, is it more practical to make 3 manual `select` elements options like in your example, or to put it into v-for loop?

Comment: It depends on your needs. If you can of course you should prefer a loop

Comment: Ok. So, I need to disable selected option from every select. And I used your `selectedValue` as array, when I change value, it's value is added to array. Now I need help how to delete old value. For example, I select `aaa` from 1st `select`, and `bbb` from 2nd `select`. And they are added to `selectedValue` array, and disabled in 3rd `select`. But now I want to change 1st `select` from `aaa` to `ccc`, so my 3rd `select` should have enabled `aaa`. I have `v-model="fieldX"` for every select, but don't know how to pass literal  `fieldX` from model and check it in my `selectedValue` string

Answer (score 0):

it's not a proper solution, please
console.log(event.target.selectedOptions);

I have not gotten multiple options to disable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).